# resource_this problem with nested resources: "can't convert Symbol into Integer"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the resource_this plugin (https://github.com/jnewland/resource_this) in a rails 3.0.7 app.  I've used it before in rails 2 apps with no problems, but this time, when i try to set a resource as being nested:

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
  resource_this :nested => [:reports] #see https://github.com/jnewland/resource_this
end
```

then try to go to one of the nested urls, eg `http://localhost:3000/reports/1/entries`, it blows up with this error:

```
Started GET "/reports/1/entries" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-06-14 09:56:11 +0100

TypeError (can't convert Symbol into Integer):
  app/controllers/entries_controller.rb:3:in `<class:EntriesController>'
  app/controllers/entries_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'

Rendered /home/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@flamingo/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (2.1ms)
Rendered /home/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@flamingo/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (5.1ms)
Rendered /home/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@flamingo/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (18.1ms)
```

If i remove the nested part, ie just have "resource_this" then it works but i don't get the automatic loading of the parent etc.  I could set this up myself but i'd like to find out why it's blowing up.  Has anyone else seen this?  The stack trace doesn't give me much to go on :/

thanks, max

EDIT - btw, i have set up the routes in case anyone was wondering if that was the problem (i don't think it is):

From my routes.rb:

```
resources :reports do
  resources :entries
end
```

And from `rake routes`

```
      report_entries GET    /reports/:report_id/entries(.:format)                            {:action=>"index", :controller=>"entries"}
                     POST   /reports/:report_id/entries(.:format)                            {:action=>"create", :controller=>"entries"}
    new_report_entry GET    /reports/:report_id/entries/new(.:format)                        {:action=>"new", :controller=>"entries"}
   edit_report_entry GET    /reports/:report_id/entries/:id/edit(.:format)                   {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"entries"}
        report_entry GET    /reports/:report_id/entries/:id(.:format)                        {:action=>"show", :controller=>"entries"}
                     PUT    /reports/:report_id/entries/:id(.:format)                        {:action=>"update", :controller=>"entries"}
                     DELETE /reports/:report_id/entries/:id(.:format)                        {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"entries"}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem caused by changes to ruby's Array#to_s method in ruby 1.9.2 - resource_this expects `[:posts].to_s` to come out as `"posts"` but in ruby 1.9.2 it comes out as `"[:posts]"`, as if you'd done Array#inspect.  This was screwing up how resource_this works out the classname of the parent.

You can work around it by saying

```
resource_this :nested => :posts
```

instead of

```
resource_this :nested => [:posts]
```

or you could use my forked version of resource_this from

https://github.com/toastkid/resource_this

:)